# BeautifulSoup not finding parents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I really can't manage to figure this out. I parsed the following [link](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=batman&s=all) with BeautifulSoup and I did this:

```
soup.find(text='Title').find_parent('h3')
```

And it does not find anything. If you take a look on the code of the linked page, you'll see a `h3` tag which contains the word `Titles`.
The exact point is:

```
<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"></a>Titles</h3>
```

If I make BS parse the line above only, it works perfectly. I tried also with:

```
soup.find(text='Title').find_parents('h3')
soup.find(text='Title').find_parent(class_='findSectionHeader')
```

which both work on the line only, but don't work on the entire html.

If I do a `soup.find(text='Titles').find_parents('div')` it works with the entire html.

Comment: There's a joke in here somewhere about you searching for parents on a page listing Batman movies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `findSectionHeader` H3 tag, there is *another* tag with `Title` in the text:

```
>>> soup.find(text='Title').parent
<a href="/find?q=batman&amp;s=tt&amp;ref_=fn_tt">Title</a>
```

You need to be more specific in your search, search for `Titles` instead, and loop to find the correct one:

```
>>> soup.find(text='Titles').parent
<option value="tt">Titles</option>
>>> for elem in soup.find_all(text='Titles'):
...     parent_h3 = elem.find_parent('h3')
...     if parent_h3 is None:
...         continue
...     print parent_h3
... 
<h3 class="findSectionHeader"><a name="tt"></a>Titles</h3>
```

`find(text='...')` only matches the *full* text, not a partial match. Use a regular expression if you need partial matches instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.find_all(text='Title')
[u'Title']
>>> soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Title'))
[u'Titles', u'Titles', u'Titles', u'Title', u'Advanced Title Search']
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a pretty stupid mistake to just assume there was only a tag with that class.